# How do I keep my Dell OptiPlex AIO from disabling the keyboard and mouse when in HDMI in mode?

Tags: multiple-monitors, kvm-switch, dell-optiplex

I have a Dell OptiPlex 9030 All-in-One computer, which has an HDMI in port. It seems that when it is on HDMI in mode rather than "computer" mode, it disables the keyboard and mouse--presumably because if you're watching TV on your computer or something, you won't want to hit something on your keyboard by mistake.

However, I would like to use the keyboard and mouse anyway. I went into the BIOS menu and looked for anything that would help me, but I didn't find anything. I can't really think of where else to change this.

Any ideas?

Comment: I suspect it wouldn't be possible - the keyboard and mouse bits are part of the 'PC' and using the HDMI in would just bypass that totally.

Comment: Does this disable the USB ports completely when using HDMI mode?

Comment: Well the PC isn't completely bypassed, because the other monitor works. I just can't do anything with it. Also, interestingly, when I keep the other monitor on and look at the device settings, I can still see the keyboard and mouse (they disappear fairly quickly when I unplug them). I can't really think of how to test to see if the USB would work for other devices, since even the keyboard and mouse don't disappear, and I can't use the computer when this happens.